# Like KeyChain structure used to store critical data?

Tags: android, security

I want to store a few critical information in android.
I do not want to use SharedPreferences because not safe and it is deleting the "clear data" property of manage applications.
I think the ideal thing for this job keychain class, but it requires api level 14.
My android app is api level 8.
How do I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can have a look here: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/ics-credential-storage-implementation.html

Answer (score 0):

> I think the ideal thing for this job keychain class, but it requires api level 14.

AFAIK, the keychain API is only for certificates, not "a few critical information".

> How do I do this?

You don't. I doubt even the keychain API is tamper-resistant, since the encryption key and algorithm are both on the device. If you do not want the user to have "a few critical information", do not put that information on the device.